# Xslt change node and add namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, namespaces

I have a following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<location>
<Destination>Des01</Destination>
<DesCode>ACD8701</DesCode>
<UniqueId>023154</UniqueId>
<Amount>26</Amount>
</location>
```

I want to change the `<location>` into `<abc_ItemUpdate>` and add namespace
so the output should look like the following after using XSLT

```
<ns0:abc_ItemUpdate xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo">
    <ns0:Destination>Des01</ns0:LegalEntity>
    <ns0:DesCode>ACD8701</ns0:DesCode>
    <ns0:UniqueId>023154</ns0:UniqueId>
    <ns0:Amount>26</ns0:Amount>
</ns0:abc_ItemUpdate>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/location">

     <xsl:element name="ns0:abc_ItemUpdate" namespace="http://yournms">
         <!-- copy attributes if any -->
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="ns0:{name()}" namespace="http://yournms">
         <!-- copy attributes if any -->
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would make one minor change: use `name="ns0:{local-name()}"` so it still works if applied to input that already uses namespace prefixes.